Hidden import "importlib_resources.trees" not found
I was trying to compile a pyqt GUI using Github actions. I have a very simple GUI which compiles fine and the executable runs fine once downloaded. But when pyinstaller is trying to compile another GUI script (which is the actual application package), it gives the following warning during compilation.
25602 WARNING: Hidden import "importlib_resources.trees" not found!
It compiles successfully but I believe it is missing something because when I run the .exe after I download it, I keep getting the following error. (packagename refers to a package that my package uses)
importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: packagename
On GitHub actions output, I see the 25602 WARNING and I wonder if this is the reason it can't find the package in the metadata during executable run)?
As per a stack overflow question, I tried creating recursive copy_metadata in the spec file, but in vain.
Any help is highly appreciated!

Was able to fix it temporarily by copying metadata in datas while setting up Analysis in the .spec file. Added datas=[] + copy_metadata('packagename') .
